# mat-select not selecting default option

Tags: angular, angular-material

select for select method. But it's not selecting the default option. while trying the same code with online editor it's working fine. Don't know why it's not working with mine.

#### HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="Please Select" name="status" [(ngModel)]="myData.selectionData">
        <mat-option value="selection1">selection 1</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="selection2">selection2</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

#### TypeScript

```
myData: any = {
  selectionData: "selection1"
}
```

Comment: It should work fine.

Comment: it's not working with me @Sajeetharan

Comment: @GopuV Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1gxno) working fine! if that is not working with your code then post the total/relevant code in the question or in the stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Please verify in your console if you have any errors for:

1. MatSelectModule
2. BrowserAnimationsModule

If you do, then you are missing importing them in your app or respective module which has the component using `mat-select`.

Here is a working Stackblitz with exactly the same code from the question. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xlumuu

Answer (score 0):

As already told It's working in online editors but not working with my code. Now I changed ngModel to value It's working fine. Thank You for your kind response.